# How to update or remove the pre installed software (such as vim) in mac os mavericks?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I've recently switched to mac os, I find that `vim` and `emacs` is pre installed, but the versions are outdated. I am wondering whether there is a way to update or remove it safely. 
I know `homebrew` and it works great. Only that it's installing a whole new version in a different directory and does not change anything about the pre installed one. Is `macport` going to work? Or it behaves like `homebrew` in this manner.

Comment: Something like `apt-get` for debian.

Answer (score 0):

A couple possible solutions you could do:

1)

Change the "`$PATH`" environment variable so another directory (e.g. "`/usr/local/bin`") which contains locally built, up-to-date versions of those apps are called before the directory where the default (MacOS included) versions of "`vim`" & "`emacs`" are kept (which is "`/usr/bin`").

Or 2)

If you're feeling aggressive, why not build and ***replace*** the default copies of "`vim`" & "`emacs`" in "`/usr/bin`" with new versions?

I suspect solution 1 will work best for you, as long as you know where the new tools are and that you have that directory *before* "`/usr/bin`" in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Yes, I think `homebrew` does exactly what you said in 1). What I am trying to know is whether there is a elegant way to solve this so that I don't have to install two sets of apps. Something like `apt-get` in debian.